# how to apply dynamic pagination for duplicate record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Eventid     Scheduleid  skill   name   
1            5           5        x
2            8           7        x
3            25          8        x
4            27          9        x
5            26          18       x
6            29          19       x
7            30          20       x
8            31          21       x
8            31          22       x
9            32          23       x
10           33          24       x 
11           34          26       x
11           34          26       x
11           34          26       x 
12           35          27       x
13           36          29       x
14           37          30       x
15           38          31       x
16           39          32       x 
17           40          33       x
18           41          34       x 
19           42          35       x
20           43          36       x
21           44          37       x 
22           44          37       x
```

this is my record i want to apply pagination per page  record in such manner  if eventid and schedule id same then it should consider 1 record and accordingly we have to display 10 record per hit so in first hit i should get 11 record in per hit because it record has 1 even and schedule id having same value but skill different so it should consider one same in 21 even it also please suggest  me how to apply pagination for this requirement

expected out put should like this

call procdure(page0 means offset value per 10 record)

```
Eventid     Scheduleid  skill   name   
1            5           5        x
2            8           7        x
3            25          8        x
4            27          9        x
5            26          18       x
6            29          19       x
7            30          20       x
8            31          21       x
8            31          22       x
9            32          23       x
10           33          24       x 
11           34          26       x
11           34          26       x
11           34          26       x
```

now if page 1 then same :

```
12           35          27       x
13           36          29       x
14           37          30       x
15           38          31       x
16           39          32       x 
17           40          33       x
18           41          34       x 
19           42          35       x
20           43          36       x
21           44          37       x 
22           44          37       x
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: set totalcountquery=@Whereclause;
 
  if(offsetvalue<recordlimit) then  
 
    set @QueryfforPagination=CONCAT(@SqlQuery," limit ",recordlimit );
    

     PREPARE querystatement FROM @QueryfforPagination;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;
  
    else 
       set  @QueryfforPagination=CONCAT(@SQLQuery," limit ",recordlimit," offset ",offsetvalue);
       PREPARE querystatement FROM @QueryfforPagination;
       EXECUTE querystatement;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;
   
    end if;  i tried like this

Comment: What do you want to do with the `skill` and `name` values, which may be different despite the `Eventid` and `Scheduleid` being the same?  Can you show your expected output?

Comment: OK wait am showing

Comment: Please edit your question and add your query to the question along with other details that are needed to answer the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  u got what i am trying to do ?

Comment: @MhanazSyed I have no idea what you are trying to do.  I gave up already :-(

Comment: i have to apply pagination @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I understand this but your logic for when to break a page isn't clear to me.

Comment: i am able to display pagination per reocord 10 10 but  from java side what i am doing if eventID and SchduleID is same then i take in one array in that case there is only 9 record display while it should 10